# Can a free IAP be acquired without a Microsoft account?

Tags: c#, uwp, in-app-purchase, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I would like to offer an IAP and make it free. I've seen that *the app*, being free, can be acquired by users not signed in with a Microsoft account. (I seem to remember that wasn't always possible.)

What about the IAP - can a free IAP be "purchased" without a MS account?

I tested on my computer, but even on an account that never owned the IAP (or app, for that matter) - it showed that the IAP is owned. Probably because another account (not a MS account!) owned it while debugging. Even though the other account did not have it installed at the time! (Yeah, a "feature" not a bug, of course...) So I'm a little weary of testing, and would like some answer with reasoning, or from a MS person, or a link to some documentation...

Answer (score 1):

> What about the IAP - can a free IAP be "purchased" without a MS account?

During the in-app purchasing phase, the customer must sign in to their Microsoft account to confirm their identity to continue the following steps. 
You can see more details in this article [The in-app purchase experience for a customer (HTML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh924350.aspx)

> Even though the other account did not have it installed at the time!

If a Microsoft account on the device bought this IAP, all other account on this device can used the IAP without purchasing it again.